# Obstructions for embedding a graph on a surface of genus g

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory, graph-minors

Kuratowski's theorem tells us the complete graph $K_5$ and the bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$ are the only obstructions to a graph being planar, ie embeddable in the plane with no edge-crossings.

> Is the list of obstructions to being able to embed a graph with no edge-crossings on the surface of genus $g$ known to be finite for all $g$?

Comment: "planar graphs on surfaces of genus $g$" isn't really what you mean, is it? Maybe change the title to something more like what's in the body, something like, "obstructions to embedding graphs in surfaces of genus $g$"?

Comment: @Dr Shello: If you think TonyH's answer is correct, it would be good to formally accept it (by clicking the checkmark).

Comment: The surename of famous mathematician was: KURATOWSKI.

Answer (score 31):

I'll just remark that the fact that every surface has a finite number of excluded minors (and also topological minors) does not require the full strength of the Graph Minors Theorem.  Indeed, the proof relies on the following three facts:

1. **The Grid Theorem**.  There exists a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, such that every graph with tree-width at least $f(n)$, contains the $n \times n$ grid as a minor.
2. **Graphs of bounded tree-width are well-quasi-ordered.**  For any $k$, the class of graphs of tree-width at most $k$ is well-quasi-ordered.
3. **Forbidden minors for surfaces do not contain arbitrarily large grid minors.**  There is a function $h: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, such that every minor-minimal graph not embeddable on a surface of genus $g$ does not contain an $h(g) \times h(g)$ grid as a minor.

All three of these facts now have very compact proofs.  In fact, proofs for (1) and (3), and a sketch of a proof of (2) can be found in Diestel's *Graph Theory* textbook.  See [here](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/) to peruse the book online.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, thx.

Answer (score 26):

Yes. [Wagner's Conjecture/Robertson and Seymour's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem) says that any graph family closed under taking minors can be defined by specifying a finite list of forbidden minors. For any surface $S$, the graphs embeddable $S$ without crossing edges forms a family closed under taking minors.

I haven't looked carefully at it but [Jim Belk's introduction to graph minor theory](http://cornellmath.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/graph-minor-theory-part-3/) seems good. On the linked page he mentions the following facts: the projective plane has 35 forbidden minors, the number for the torus is in the <strike>hundreds</strike> thousands (at least, the precise number/collection is not known), and in general the number of forbidden minors grows exponentially with the genus.

Comment: In fact, for the torus there are more than 16,000 known forbidden minors!  (See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411488 .)

Comment: Which begs the question: why do 2 forbidden minors are enough in the plane? I mean, why so few?

Comment: What's the approx number for genus 2?

Answer (score 5):

For the projective plane, i.e. the nonorientable surface of genus 1, this is known. Look at "A Kuratowski Theorem for the Projective Plane" in the homepage of Dan Archdeacon here:
http://www.emba.uvm.edu/~archdeac/
This was his PhD thesis. In particular, he found that there are exactly 103 graphs such that if any graph $G$ contains one of these graphs as a subgraph, then $G$ cannot be not embedded into projective plane. You can refer to his original thesis for the list of the 103 graphs, or you can refer to the Appendix A of the book "Graphs on Surfaces" by Bojan Mohar and Carsten Thomassen.

Comment: Minor (no pun intended) remark: a graph is embeddable on the projective plane if and only if it does not contain a *subdivision* of one of the 103 said graphs.  The excluded minors for the projective plane are also known; there are 35 of them.