# Minor-closed classes of graphs with large numbers of excluded minors

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

Robertson and Seymour tell us that any minor-closed family of graphs has a finite collection of excluded minors.

Standard examples include planar graphs with two excluded minors ($K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$) and knotlessly embeddable graphs with the Petersen family as excluded minors.

However in general, a finite list is not necessarily a short list, and there are natural properties with large numbers of excluded minors. In fact, I recall seeing examples where astronomical numbers of excluded minors have been proved to exist - unfortunately for the life of me, I can't remember these examples and I can't find them on MathSciNet.

So my question is: please give me references to results that show the existence of vast numbers of excluded minors for natural minor-closed classes of graphs.

Comment: The answer by Louigi Addario-Berry of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46655 is relevant.

Comment: Does anyone know whether there is a finite upper bound? Might there be some number $N$ for which, for every minor-closed family of graphs has a set of no more than $N$ forbidden minors? I'd guess there is no such upper bound, but I can't even guess how to prove such a thing, one way or the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is another answer that I just recently learned about that I find quite shocking.  A graph is called $Y \Delta Y$ *reducible* if it can be reduced to isolated vertices by applying any of the following six operations.

1. Delete a loop.
2. Delete a degree one vertex.
3. Replace a pair of parallel edges by a single edge.
4. Replace an induced path by a single edge.
5. $Y \Delta$  transformation: Delete a degree 3 vertex $w$ and its three incident edges $wx,
   wy$ and $wz$, and add three edges $xy, yz$ and $xz$.
6. $\Delta Y$ transformation: Delete the three edges of a triangle $\Delta:=xyz$, and add a new vertex $w$ and three new edges $wx, wy$ and $wz.$

Truemper showed that the class of $Y \Delta Y$ reducible graphs is minor-closed.  Epifanov proved that all planar graphs are $Y \Delta Y$ reducible.  Recently, [Yu](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/EJC/Volume_13/PDF/v13i1r7.pdf) showed that there are more than 68 billion excluded minors for $Y \Delta Y$ reducibility.

Specically, Yu finds 68897913659 graphs that are excluded minors (up to isomorphism).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a follow-up to Richard Stanley's comment.  In his Master's thesis *Hunting for torus obstructions* (University of Victoria, 2002), Chambers (together with his adviser Myrvold) studied the forbidden minors (and forbidden topological minors) for embeddability on the torus.

According to this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411488):

> To date, Myrvold and Chambers have found 239,322 topological
>   obstructions and 16,629 minor order obstructions that include those on up
>   to eleven vertices, the 3-regular ones on up to 24 vertices, the disconnected
>   ones and those with a cut-vertex. Previously, only a few thousand had been
>   determined.

I am guessing that this was done by computer search, but I couldn't access the thesis from the UVic library.

Comment: That's good.. well, good in the sense of cautionary example which is what I was looking for - several hundred thousand obstructions for what seems to be a natural property. 

Comment: Yes, it was done by computer search.